# Ajax-Django : Send signal

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

In my website, I have a button for join a team.

I try to have this processus :

1. Click on this button.
2. Ajax send a signal to current template view.
3. This view recepts the signal and creates a instance of model Join.

I don't want ajax send arguments via $.POST but just a signal !

I think the solution is :

```
$.POST("theurl/",{"signal-join":"signal"});

if request.POST["signal-join"] :
    create instance of join
```

But it's not proper, what is the best away ?

Comment: If you have no prohibition to join.

Comment: What ? ^^ A user can't join a team if he is blocked by admin...

Comment: If you don't want to send any data, you could sent `GET` instead of `POST`.

Comment: So I choose the solution which consists to send any data via POST.. just $.POST("url"); Thank's